# syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED) in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor, codeigniter-3

### Admin_controller

```
<?php
class Admin_controller extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("Adminmodel","",true);
        
        protected $headerview = 'headerview';
        protected function render($content) { 
            //$view_data = array( 'content' => $content);
            $this->load->view($this->headerview);
        }
     }
}
?>
```

I want to access my headerview.php in all pages of application so that I have created like above but it showing error like  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci3\application\controllers\admin\Admin_controller.php`.
How to solve this?

Comment: use public() function

Comment: after used public() function same error.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? `__construct` it self a function. And you are defining new function inside `__construct`?

Comment: why defining new function inside constructor ?

Comment: i have taken out that render function from __construct function. Now its working.

Comment: I had the same issue, just because I forgot to close a curly barrack of function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is **no way to create function inside the `__construct`**

```
class Admin_controller extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("Adminmodel","",true);

        $headerview = 'headerview';
        $this->render($headerview); # calling render() function in same class

    }

    function render($content) 
    { 
        //$view_data = array( 'content' => $content);
        $this->load->view($this->headerview);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kevin happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposing creating/declaring a function inside contructor with access modifier,otherwise it will throws an errors like you did. You can create anonymous function or normal function declaration instead, consider this :

```
class Student {

  public function __construct() {

    // below code will run successfull
    function doingTask () {
       echo "hey";    
    }
    doingTask();

    // but this will throw an error because of declaring using access modifier
    public function doingTask () {
       echo "hey";    
    }
  }
}

$std = new Student;
```